# oauth not found on Umbraco.Web.Editors.BackOfficeController with v7.4.1

Tags: oauth, controller, umbraco, token

I use `VisualStudio v14`, recently upgraded to `7.4.1` via the NuGet package manager and Umbraco is now returning a server error page `"Server Error in '/' Application" - replying with a 404 for "/umbraco/oauth/token"` when I make token requests. The error also states, A public action method 'oauth' was not found on controller `'Umbraco.Web.Editors.BackOfficeController'`.

I had the base Umbraco RestApi configuration working just fine in my previous installation of 7.3.8.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled the Umbraco RestApi and IdentityExtensions, validated my configurations in both Web.config and UmbracoStandardOwinStartup.cs, rebuilt my site and still getting a 404 server error. I have also validated that my UrlRewriting.config is not interfering with the request

Here is the token request I use:

```
curl -X POST -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -d 'grant_type=password&username=admin&password=pwd' http://localhost:12345/umbraco/oauth/token
```

Does anyone have any suggestions how I can debug, or better yet a solution for me?

Answer (score 0):

Token authorization using the `/umbraco/oauth/token` service path requires a HTTPS protocol. Even though Production and/or enterprise managed servers have SSL properly configured, our PDEs seldom are.

Here's what I did to enable SSL in my `Visual Studio 2015` `.NET 4.5.2` web site project for my Umbraco instance.

In the `*.csproj` file find the node: `<IISExpressSSLPort />` and change it to: `<IISExpressSSLPort>44300</IISExpressSSLPort>` FYI - the port number must be between 44300 and 44399 and make sure these ports are open on your PDE. Visual Studio will prompt you to make some determinations about it's behavior towards this new SSL configuration and future SSL configurations, so those determinations are up to you.

So here's a working request for a token from the localhost:

`curl -X POST -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -d 'grant_type=password&username=######&password=******' -k https://localhost:44300/umbraco/oauth/token`

Notice the `-k` flag.

Because I opted to install a local SSL generated by VS, the verification by `curl` fails, so the `-k` flag is used to disable the verification for the current request.

I hope this helps anyone who stumbles upon this thread! Good luck!